How to use Pandera to cross check if some substrings in one column are present in other column?
I have a Pandas DataFrameSchema like this:
Schema = DataFrameSchema(
   columns={
        'Complete_Name': Column(name='Complete_Name', dtype='string', nullable=True),
        'Surname': Column(name='Surname', dtype='string', nullable=True),
    }, 
   checks=check_cross_check_name_and_surname, 
   coerce=True, 
   strict=True, 
   ordered=False, 
   unique_column_names=True, 
   metadata=None
)

The check should work like this SQL query here (Each Complete Name must have a Surname associated with it):
SELECT * FROM database.user 
WHERE Complete_Name LIKE '%'||Surname||'%'

I have tried things like
check_cross_check_name_and_surname = [pa.Check(lambda df: df["Complete_Name"].str.contains(df["Surname"], regex=True), element_wise=True, ignore_na=False)]

check_cross_check_name_and_surname = [pa.Check(lambda df: df["Complete_Name"].str.contains(df["Surname"], regex=False), element_wise=True, ignore_na=False)]

check_cross_check_name_and_surname = [pa.Check(lambda df: df["Surname"] in df["Complete_Name"], element_wise=True, ignore_na=False)] 

What I need to write to make sure my tests run correctly when I call Schema.validate(dataframe)?
